# cmake: problems specifying the compiler

Tags: windows, gcc, makefile, g++, cmake

I have a problem with this CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++)

project(cmake_test)

add_executable(a.exe test.cpp)
```

Calling cmake with:  `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

I get:

```
c:\cmake_test>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.1
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake:1 (SET):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/cmake_test/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake:1

  when parsing string

    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc

  Invalid escape sequence \M

  Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.1
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1 (SET):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/cmake_test/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1

  when parsing string

    C:\MinGW\bin\g++

  Invalid escape sequence \M

  Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad variable reference syntax is an error.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0010" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Check for working C compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc
CMake Error at C:/cmake_test/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake:1 (SET):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/cmake_test/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake:1

  when parsing string

    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc

  Invalid escape sequence \M
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
CMake Error: your C compiler: "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "C:\MinGW\bin\g++" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I also tried with:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++
/C/MinGW/bin/g++
```

with the same result. Double quotes have not been helpful, either.

Of course, the compiler is present in the specified directory.

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: `SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/gcc)` is a bit easier to use.

Comment: Nice, a mixture of Windows and Unix syntax ;-)

Comment: FYI: forward slashes have been supported since [DOS 2.0](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23123-when-did-windows-start-accepting-forward-slash-path-separator)!

Comment: and it looks like you need ".exe" on the end of the filenames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use *four* backslashes to get a literal backslash in a `SET`:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:\\\\MinGW\\\\bin\\\\gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:\\\\MinGW\\\\bin\\\\g++)
```

This applies whether or not you use quotes around the argument.

Since this is pretty ugly, it's probably better to use forward slashes:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/g++)
```

Comment: It is the first time I see four backslashes together! They should add it to the documentation...

Comment: When setting a CMake variable that is a path to a directory or file name, use "/" as the separator character.

Comment: However, you should avoid setting the _COMPILER variables directly in the CMakeLists.txt file. See my answer to your "(2)" version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13089688/236192