# How to prefix CMake Compiler?

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

I want to prefix the compiler with a utility script, so instead of for example `g++-4.7 main.cpp`,`kinst-ompp g++-4.7 main.cpp` is invoked.

I tried doing this in the CMakeLists.txt, but I'm getting a "not found" error:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${OMPP_CXX} ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${OMPP_CC} ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
```

How do I properly configure this using CMake?

Comment: If you're using the Makefile generator, Try running `VERBOSE=1 make` after running cmake. That way, you can see exactly which commands get invoked by make - maybe it helps debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by setting my compiler to the prefix and then passing the real compiler name as first argument. Ugly, I know.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${OMPP_CXX}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${commonCXXFlags} ${commonReleaseFlags}")
```

Comment: This works only if some CMAKE script is not prefixing CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE by something (e.g. preprocessor define.) If this happens you will get undecipherable errors during compilation. Fraser's answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid setting the compiler in this way - see [cmake: problems specifying the compiler (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054451/cmake-problems-specifying-the-compiler-2) and this [CMake FAQ entry](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F) for more info.

I think the following should work (after deleting your CMakeCache.txt):

```
export CC="kinst-ompp gcc-4.7" CXX="kinst-ompp g++-4.7" cmake <Path to CMakeLists.txt>
```

Comment: This leads to the error "could not find compiler set in environment variable CC"...