# Setting a cmake prefix compiler command

Tags: profiler, prefix

I need to profile a C/C++ program. I'm using cmake, and all my compile configurations are set up in a CMakeList. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897370/how-to-prefix-cmake-compiler), there is an ugly way to do this. There is another solution [here](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Using-MPI-Profiler-Scalasca-in-Cmake-td7585595.html), but it did not work in my case. So, as explained [here](https://wiki.hpcc.msu.edu/display/hpccdocs/Parallel+profiling+with+Scalasca), I must translate a configuration like this

```
export CC="skin icc"
export CXX="skin icpc"
....
make

or

make CC="skin icc" CXX="skin icpc"....
```

into a CMakeList configuration. In my current CMakeList, I have not set up the compilers. Only flags are defined

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -fopenmp -o3")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -fopenmp -o3")
```

Any help would be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This is a Q& A site. What is your question?

Comment: "I must translate a configuration like this <code> into a CMakeList configuration". As can be seen in my post.

Comment: 1) There is no language C/C++ 2) This is not about any of the two different languages C or C++. CMake is not related to any of them. 3) What is your **specific** question? We are not a "do my job/hjomework/assignment/…" site.

Comment: @tnas, this is an assignment, not a question. Why wouldn't solve assignments for you.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to correct the post. But, my problem is: I have a C/C++ project and I'm using CMake for compile it. But I need to profile this code. I don't know how to add the profile command in the CMakeList.

Comment: @tnas: What did your last comment state your question did not already? Repeating the know like a mantra is not really helpful.

Comment: Let me try again: How to set a prefix compiler command in a CMakeList?

Answer (score -1):

This is what has solved in this case. After setting the project name, I've added this snippet of script:

```
set(PROFILER_ENABLED ON)

set(SCOREP_PROFILER "scorep")
set(COMPILER_FLAGS "-Wall -fopenmp -o3")
set(CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS "g++ ${COMPILER_FLAGS}")
set(C_COMPILER_FLAGS "gcc ${COMPILER_FLAGS}")

if(PROFILER_ENABLED)
    foreach(LANG C CXX)
        message(STATUS "Enabling scorep for ${LANG}")
        set(CMAKE_${LANG}_COMPILER "${SCOREP_PROFILER}")
        set(CMAKE_${LANG}_FLAGS "${${LANG}_COMPILER_FLAGS}")
    endforeach()
else()
    message(STATUS "Default compilers")
    foreach(LANG C CXX)
        set(CMAKE_${LANG}_FLAGS "${COMPILER_FLAGS}")
    endforeach()
endif()
```