# CXX CMake compiler prefix with executable not working

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, parasoft

I am following Parasoft code coverage to run it on my source code : https://docs.parasoft.com/display/CPPTEST1040/Instrumenting+and+Building+Instrumented+Source+Code

I have defined CXX as an environment variable in my new conan profile.

```
[env]
CXX="cpptestcc -compiler gcc_5-64 -line-coverage -workspace /home/test/proj -- c++"
```

As I wanted to run the Parasoft code coverage on my Conan based project.

```
conan install . -pr=myprofile
```

[image]

```
conan build .
```

[image]

The problem is that, I am not able to prepend the CXX compiler with parasoft code coverage. Running into CXX compiler broken as it is not taking the complete CXX as defined in the conan profile.

I have seen lot of links in stackoverflow related to this: [How to prefix CMake Compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897370/how-to-prefix-cmake-compiler)

Nothing works in my case. Please help me in defining the CXX with an executable prepended to CXX.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please do not post images of the logs, or config files. Post the **actual text** in your question post.

Comment: take a look on CMake docs about coverage: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Coverage

Comment: @uilianries But this link does not help my situation to prepend compiler with an executable. The link is talking about totally different tool. But thanks for replying.

Comment: The problem is that CMake is not able to deal to your command. Conan can't solve it because CXX is consumed directly by CMake.

Comment: Any idea how we could acheive this CMake? This would help me a lot.

Comment: is the CXX flag identical during the configuration step ?