# CMake error while compiling linphone android project in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cmake, linphone

I am new in linphone. I clone linphone git repo [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android), I got error when i am going to compiling linphone project.

As mention step in linphone github page [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android), follow all the step. and install required software in ubuntu 16.04.

When i am going to do `./prepare.py -ac` or `./prepare.py -L` got same error.

Issues is,

```
/linphone-android$ ./prepare.py ac
cmake /home/krunal/linphone-android/submodules/cmake-builder -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/krunal/linphone-android/liblinphone-sdk/android-arm -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/krunal/linphone-android/liblinphone-sdk/android-arm -DLINPHONE_BUILDER_WORK_DIR=/home/krunal/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchains/toolchain-android-arm.cmake -DLINPHONE_BUILDER_CONFIG_FILE=configs/config-android.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE=LAZY -DLINPHONE_BUILDER_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATH=/home/krunal/linphone-android/submodules -DENABLE_VIDEO=NO -G "Unix Makefiles" -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=YES -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=YES -DENABLE_AMRNB=YES -DENABLE_AMRWB=YES -DENABLE_BV16=YES -DENABLE_CODEC2=YES -DENABLE_G729=YES -DENABLE_GSM=YES -DENABLE_ILBC=YES -DENABLE_ISAC=YES -DENABLE_OPUS=YES -DENABLE_SILK=YES -DENABLE_SPEEX=YES -DENABLE_FFMPEG=YES -DENABLE_H263=YES -DENABLE_H263P=YES -DENABLE_MPEG4=YES -DENABLE_OPENH264=YES -DENABLE_VPX=YES
CMake Error at toolchains/android/toolchain-android.cmake:53 (message):
Cannot find the compiler
Call Stack (most recent call first):
toolchains/toolchain-android-arm.cmake:27 (include)
/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
CMakeLists.txt


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Well, you have to set the C and the C++ compiler. Have you installed an appropriate compiler at all?

Comment: @usr1234567 No i am not installing any c compiler in system. So, which compiler is used in cmake. Can i go with gcc compiler...?

Comment: CMake is unrelated to your compiler. Probably some GCC is needed. You should learn more about cross compiling and do some tutorial or read a book.

Comment: I have the same problem. I do have Command line tool installed, which implied that I have gcc, I suppose.

Comment: @scat95 What you are saying...? I am not getting your point.

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya You must use a compiler to compile it. If you set your compiler with the `-D` option you can compile it.

Comment: @Krunal Indrodiya I also have error saying that gcc compiler is not found, but when you install Command line tool, it also ships gcc compiler. As @ usr1234567 pointed out above - it might be related to the fact, that there is no gcc compiler.

Comment: @scat95 As you told, which command line tool i have to install in system. I am using ubuntu and teminal is inbuilt.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am on OS X and Command Line Tool brings gcc compiler with it. So, in your case, I suppose you have to make sure that you have a gcc compiler. This might be one of the issues. I do not know if ubuntu has the gcc compiler by default or not.

Comment: @scat95 Yup in ubuntu gcc and g++ compiler install successfully, with version is 6.0.0. Still issues is same.

Comment: Are you build linphone using root?

Comment: @FabCoder Yes, and i build it. issue is android ndk version. Thanks.

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya yes i also have same type of error and its related to Android NDK

Comment: @FabCoder can i talk in chat...? I want to talk with u.

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya yes

Comment: @FabCoder Join on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112496/linphone-android

Answer (score 0):

Set your compiler, and have a compiler with the `-D`option:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc
```

Related: [cmake: problems specifying the compiler (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054451/cmake-problems-specifying-the-compiler-2)

Comment: still have same issue.