# how cmake Error in compiling for riscv64-unknown-elf-g++

Tags: cmake, cmake-format

The error looks like the below when I cmake .. from the terminal:

```
(base) k:~ cd /Users/yuli/Documents/version3/cpp/
(base) k:~ ls
CMakeLists.txt      src
riscv-gnu-toolchain test
(base) k:~ mkdir build
(base) k:~ cd build
(base) k:~ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
RegularExpression::compile(): Nested *?+.
RegularExpression::compile(): Error in compile.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++" "MATCHES" ".*riscv64-unknown-elf-g++"

  Regular expression ".*riscv64-unknown-elf-g++" cannot compile


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/yuli/Documents/version3/cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I tried "STREQUAL" instead of MATCHES but didn't work. any idea what might be wrong in here?

CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(ofdmchain)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14")

add_definitions(-DCOMPILES_ON_PC -Wall -Wextra)

configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/config.hpp.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.hpp)

if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" MATCHES ".*riscv64-unknown-elf-g++")
  message(STATUS "Compiling RISCV")
  SET(RISCV 1)
else()
  message(STATUS "Compiling X86")
  SET(RISCV 0)
endif()

add_library(ofdm
  src/transmitter.cpp
  src/configuration.cpp

  src/ofdm.hpp
  src/datatypes.hpp
  )
target_include_directories(ofdm PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../reference_matlab)
target_include_directories(ofdm PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/)

if (NOT ${RISCV})
  add_executable(unit_tests
    test/catch_main.cpp
    test/test_sanity.cpp
    test/test_utilities.cpp
    test/test_transmitter.cpp
    )
  target_include_directories(unit_tests PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
  target_include_directories(unit_tests PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
  target_link_libraries(unit_tests ofdm)
endif()
```

I have also tried adding ++ where g++ exits as well as - where - exists. And also have tired "STREQUAL" instead of "MATCHES" it didn't work either. It could be the problem of c++ in the PATH?

Comment: Could You please add the CMakeLists segment in question? From the error message is not that trivial to guess, what exactly are You trying to do.

Comment: \+\+ and \- I meant.

Answer (score 1):

CMake "internal error"

```
RegularExpression::compile(): Nested *?+.
```

is about the last two `+` characters: in regular expressions such characters has special meaning.

Ways for make `+` character (and other special characters) to be treated *literally*:

1. **Escape** the character with `\`. Note, that *escape character* by itself should be escaped in CMake string, so you need to write it **twice**:

   ```
   if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" MATCHES ".*riscv64-unknown-elf-g\\+\\+")
   ```
2. Put the character into **square brackets** (`[]`). Inside `[]` all special characters loose their special meaning:

   ```
   if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" MATCHES ".*riscv64-unknown-elf-g[+][+]")
   ```

---

Note also, that in certain `if` conditions one doesn't need to explicitly **dereference** the variable: CMake does that by itself.

So, it is possible to write

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER MATCHES ".*riscv64-unknown-elf-g[+][+]")
```

See more in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/if.html#variable-expansion) for `if` command.

Comment: If I do the above it is not detecting the riscv64 compiler at all. It is skipping to else condition directly. I tried everything mentioned above.

Comment: It works for me if compiler is `foo-riscv64-unknown-elf-g++`. Which compiler do you use, so it doesn't match the regular expression?

Comment: (base) k:~ riscv64-unknown-elf-g++ --version
riscv64-unknown-elf-g++ (GCC) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: `riscv64-unknown-elf-g++` matches for me too, e.g. using the second approach with `[+]`. Are you sure that `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variable is assigned exactly this value? You may print the value of the variable using `message` command.

Comment: To be frank I am new to Linux and just using at the moment to compiler cpp code using riscv64 compiler for a project. But I am unable to compile the code successfully. But when I try this echo $CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER the ouput is nothing.

Comment: `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is a **CMake** variable, not an environment one. You may print value of this variable in `CMakeLists.txt` by `message("CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")`. It will be printed during the configuration of your project. Note, that variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variable is set inside the `project()` call, so checking it before this call is useless.

Comment: I am using mac OS with g++ and riscv64-unknown-elf-g++  installed and trying to compile a cpp code and checking whether the code compiles successfully with riscv64-unknown-elf-g++ compiler.

Comment: With that I got this message: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++

Comment: how can I assign the value to a CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER variable?

Comment: "how can I assign the value to a CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER variable?" - Just google for  "cmake set compiler". See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054451/unable-to-specify-the-compiler-with-cmake

Comment: Thank you will take a look at it.